# If a has attr rel=lightbox then addClass, problem

Tags: jquery, lightbox, addclass, attr

I wonder why this doesn't work?

```
var attr = $("a").attr('rel');
if (typeof attr == 'lightBox') {
    $(this).addClass("lightbox");
}
```

I want to add a class to a link which has the REL attribute set to "lightBox".

This should work... right?

Comment: A bit of pure javascript learning couldn't hurt, you should read a few js tutorials before starting with jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('a[rel="lightbox"]').addClass("lightbox");
```

That should do the trick.

typeof - returns the data type NOT the value! so you are trying to compare type (string) to value (lightBox).

Comment: IE7 is case-sensitive, apparently. Couldn't find out why it didn't work... :-)

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` will never work in this context (you want to compare the string's content instead, i.e. `if (attr == 'lightBox')`), and `this` will not be available in that context either, or at least not show to the desired element.

Why not simply do a

```
$("a[rel='lightBox']").addClass("lightBox");
```

?

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work.

`typeof` tests the *type* of the attribute - in this case, the `rel` attribute is always a string. Take out the typeof, it won't work.

Also, where has `$this` come from?